Question on homotopy for Koszul Complex
I am working on illustrating the relationship between the originally defined Koszul complex and its dual version by examining the definitions of the differentials we define for the Koszul complex.
For $x\in M$ and $\phi:M\rightarrow R,$ I aim to demonstrate that $d_x\delta_{\phi}+\delta_{\phi}d_x=\phi(x)\cdot 1,$ here $d_x$ refers to the differentials in $K(x)$ and $\delta_{\phi}$ refers to the differentials in $K(\phi).$
I am focusing on the base case shown below:
$$
   \bigwedge^{2} M \rightarrow M\otimes_R\bigwedge^{1} M \rightarrow R\otimes_R R= R 
$$
where we have $\Delta:\bigwedge^{2} M \rightarrow M\otimes_R\bigwedge^{1} M$
$$
        \Delta(m_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge m_{i})=\sum\limits_{t=1}^{i}(-1)^{t-1}m_{t}\otimes m_1\wedge\dots\wedge \hat{m}_{t}\wedge\dots\wedge m_{i}
$$
and $\phi\otimes 1:M\otimes_R\bigwedge^{1} M \rightarrow R\otimes_R R= R$.
For $m\in\bigwedge^1 M$
\begin{align*}
        d_x\circ\varphi(m)+\varphi\circ d_x(m)
        &=x
        \wedge \varphi(m)+\varphi(x\wedge m)\\
        &=x\wedge \varphi(m)+\phi\otimes 1(\Delta(x\wedge m))\\
        &=x\wedge \varphi(m)+\phi\otimes 1(x\otimes m-m\otimes x)\\
        &=x\wedge \varphi(m)+(\phi(x)\otimes m-\phi(m)\otimes x)\\
        &=x\wedge (\phi\otimes 1(\Delta(m)))+\phi(x)\otimes m-\phi(m)\otimes x\\
        &=x\wedge \phi(m) +\phi(x)\otimes m-\phi(m)\otimes x
\end{align*}
I'm in trouble and I don't know how to go on. I follow these notation in Eisenbud's book,  thanks for any advice!
